# Could we use owl:sameAs in an OWL restriction?

Tags: owl, restriction

For example, I have three classes: Flock, Bird, Velocity. I also have two properties: hasMember (the domain is Flock, range is Bird), and hasAttribute (the domain is Bird, and the range is Velocity). Now I want to add a EquivalentClass restriction to Flock class as the definition. Let consider a very simple definition: in a flock, all birds have the same velocity. How to express this in OWL?

Comment: As a workaround, you can declare property `hasAttribute` with `Flock` as its domain and write simple SWRL rule.

Comment: Thank you Stanislav. I know it can be expressed in rules. I'm just wondering if only OWL axioms could do that.

Comment: OWL is variable-free, i.e. you cannot make statements about the velocity for all individuals of a particular class unless you have a specific value that can be used. Therefore, SWRL exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** this answer is in fact incorrect, please look at the comments to see why.

To the question "Could we use `owl:sameAs` in an OWL restriction?" the answer is no, not in an OWL (2) ontology. However, you can do whatever you like in an OWL Full ontology (i.e., an RDF graph interpreted according to the OWL RDF-based semantics). Yet, this is irrelevant to the details of your question where you want to say something about the velocity of the birds in a flock.

There is a solution to your problem within the limits of OWL 2 DL. Introduce a property  `flockVelocity` and make the property chain `hasMember o hasAttribute` a subproperty of `flockVelocity`. Make `flockVelocity` a functional property and you're done. Alternatively, you could define a cardinality restriction on `flockVelocity`. In Turtle:

```
:hasMember a owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain :Flock;
    rdfs:range :Bird .
 :hasAttribute a owl:ObjectProperty; # why not :hasVelocity?
    rdfs:domain :Bird;
    rdfs:range :Velocity .
 :flockVelocity a owl:ObjectProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty;
    owl:propertyChainAxiom (:hasMember :hasAttribute) .
```

Done. If you don't care about being in OWL DL and allow yourself total OWL Full freedom, you could use a blank node instead of `:flockVelocity` such that you don't have to introduce an artificial property name.

Comment: Thanks Antoine. I tried the the property chain. However, if I make flockVelocity as a functional property, run HermiT, a internal reasoner error occurs: "An error occurred during reasoning: Non-simple property '<...#flockVelocity>' or its inverse appears in the cardinality restriction 'ObjectMaxCardinality(1 <...#flockVelocity> <...#Velocity>)'.. " So I added the cardinality restriction to Flock class, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @deerls, see [11.2 The Restrictions on the Axiom Closure](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#The_Restrictions_on_the_Axiom_Closure), "Restriction on Simple Roles" and "Restriction on the Property Hierarchy" paragraphs.

Comment: Aaaah, you are right and I am wrong! My ontology is not in OWL 2 DL because of the reason Stanislas mentioned. However, it may be possible to get the desired result with a cardinality restriction. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: In fact, cardinality restrictiond on composite properties (the properties associated to a property chain axiom) are not allowed either, so there is definitely no way to express this in the limits of OWL 2 DL. Feel free to downvote my misleading answer.